Manhwa where the male lead is in the future and the female lead is in the past, so they met through their dreams

The female lead is older than the male lead (2/3 years)
The female lead had committed suicide, so the male lead can't find her in real life
There was a scene where the female lead writes her name on a bench in a park at night and it appears in the future where the male lead was sitting, as they were sitting in the same spot in different timelines
They went to the same uni, but can't find each other because of the differing timelines and the female lead having committed suicide a few years ago in the male lead's time
The female lead has black hair and eyes
they meet at the park at night on the same bench after ml fell asleep on the park bench then wake up at fl timeline

I read this a long time ago (maybe about 1 year ago) so I don't remember the name. If anyone knows the name then please help

This sounds eerily like Your Name, except it isn't a manga and the FL doesn't die by suicide.

The manhwa’s name is Please Show Up! (Or Natanajuseyo).


One day, Kim Jiyong, an ordinary student, dreams of Jung Jihye and falls in love with her at first sight. But when he tries to find her... it turns out that the woman committed suicide 2 years ago?!

I really enjoyed it back when I read what was up, but couldn’t find the whole thing since I think the translator I was reading from dropped it. Let me know if you can find a version with all the chapters!

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you please describe how this manga matches the details mentioned in the question?  If it's not available to link to, we need some additional information here.

https://bato.to/series/89291/please-show-up Thank you, I read it from here though this translation is not complete yet but yes, I like this story It is quite unique

ohh and it's full version is on Naver Webtoon,there it's complete
